# Size of an NL TM

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

On page 325 of Sipser, he gives a proof that PATH is NL-Complete which says basically that we can create a graph where each node is a configuration of a TM, and then solving if a path exists determines if the TM accepts:

> Each node is a configuration of $M$ on $w$ and can be represented in $c\log n$ space for some constant $c$. The transducer sequentially goes through all possible strings of length $c\log n$, tests whether each is a legal configuration of $M$ on $w$, and outputs those that pass the test. [I believe $n$=length($w$)]

If M runs in log space, then there are $s^{O(\log (n))}$ possible configurations its tape can be in (if there are $s$ symbols).

So how can we construct a list of all possible configurations of a log space TM in log space? There are potentially more than $O(\log n)$ valid configurations, so storing the enumeration seems impossible.

Comment: You don't have to store them, you can calculate them each time you need them instead of storing them, which is possible.

Comment: $s^{O(\log n)}$ need not be $O(n)$.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Good point. It is $\geq O(n)$ though, right?

Comment: @Xodarap: Just to be pedantic, the expression $\geq O(n)$ is non-sensical. What you wanted to say is that $s^{\Theta(\log n)}$ is $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: @JeremyHurwitz: Indeed, forgive my naivete. Hopefully the thrust of my question is still understandable, even if the terms are wrong.

Comment: @DimitriSurinx: Could you expand? Even if you calculate on the fly each configuration, you would need some way of storing which configs you've tried etc.

Comment: Well, hence it is nondeterministic, one simple counter should suffice to keep track of the already visited configurations.

Comment: $s^{\theta(\log n)}$ could be $o(n)$ (note: small Oh). For instance, $e^{\frac{\log n}{2}} = \sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how can we construct a list of all possible configurations of a log space TM in log space? There are potentially more than $O(\log n)$ valid configurations, so storing the enumeration seems impossible.

You are correct in saying that there are potentially more than $O(\log n)$ configurations. Indeed, there could be polynomially many (since $2^{O(\log n)}=n^{O(1)}$).

However, we don't need to store the enumeration -- we only need to compute it on demand. This is the key insight to log-space reductions, so it's worth expanding on this point. Functionally, a list is simply a data structure that takes an index and returns the corresponding element. In other words, it's just a function $f:[N]\rightarrow\Sigma^*$. One way of implementing $f$ is to literally list the values. For highly-structured lists, however, it's far more space-efficient to compress the data.

For example, the function $f:[N]\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ implements the all-zeroes list using only constant space. I realize that this is obvious and trivial, but it highlights some surprisingly deep insights. Note that if we query $f(x)$ 100 times, then we'll calculate $f(x)$, *from scratch*, 100 times. For complicated compression schemes, this could severely hurt the time efficiency of the algorithm. [*Fun fact*: the [optimal compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) can take arbitrarily long to unpack.]

Getting back to NL-completeness: We can think of the input as a list, with the input-head implicitly acting as a counter $\textit{index}$ containing the current location. Moving the head left corresponds to subtracting 1, while moving it right corresponds to adding 1. Since the input has length $n$, explicitly storing $\textit{index}$ only requires an additional $\log n$ space. Reading from the input is really querying $x(\textit{index})$.

The transducer effectively intercepts this query to $x(\textit{index})$ and calculates the answer.

One final note: the definition of a log-space transducer doesn't say anything about asking for the $k$-th bit of the output. We can get it in this form by adding a single counter (using $O(\log n)$ bits) that stores how many bits of output have been computed. Whenever the transducer would have written to the output tape, it instead increments the counter. Upon reaching $k$, it returns that value.